# main has not been registered [react-native-navigation/wix]

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I’m working on a react-native app using react-native-navigation from wix, and I’m following the installation instructions as shown here: https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/docs/installing/

But after installing pods and running the app the following error occurs:
“main” has not been registered.
And that’s because, as shown in the tutorial, the registerRootComponent row must be removed.
How can i solve this error?
Thank you